# RecyclerView only shows 1 item when I use LinearLayout instead of CardView as the parent XML layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Here's my XML Fragment:

**fragment_leaderboards.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/leaderboards_list"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and my custom view for the LayoutInflater of the ViewHolder:

**leaderboard_item.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leaderboard_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgShare"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:tint="#eeeeee"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The above XML will only show 1 item of my RecyclerView. It will also show only 1 item of RecyclerView if I put the CardView inside the LinearLayout: `<LinearLayout><Cardview>...</Cardview></LinearLayout>`

However, if I wrap the `LinearLayout`in a `CardView`, it will show all items (which is 2 at the moment): `<Cardview><LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout></Cardview>`.

Why is this?

Here's my Kotlin code if you're curious:

**fragment**

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leaderboards, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        val viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*> = LeaderboardsAdapter(arrayListOf(Player("James", 23, "male"), Player("Jane", 22, "female")))
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = leaderboards_list.apply {
            adapter = viewAdapter
            layoutManager = viewManager
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
    }
```

**LeaderboardsAdapter.kt**

```
class LeaderboardsAdapter(private val players: ArrayList<Player>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LeaderboardsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    class ViewHolder(val v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LeaderboardsAdapter.ViewHolder {
        Log.d("Viewgroup", "$parent.toString() $parent.")
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.leaderboard_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LeaderboardsAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.v.leaderboard_name.text = players[position].name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = players.size

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My LinearLayout had `android:layout_height="match_parent"` so the 1 item was taking up the whole screen - that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, either you can set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or fix height as per your view requirement. See this is very common among android developers. Good Luck for next time.